# DOM manipulation of proxy response in express node using Cheerio and http-proxy-middleware

Tags: node.js, express, cheerio, dom-manipulation, http-proxy-middleware

I've setup proxy server in express Node, which is working fine.

```
const express = require('express');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const app = express();

// Define your proxy rules here
app.use(
  '/', // Replace with the path you want to proxy
  createProxyMiddleware({
    target: 'https://www.lemonade.com/',
    changeOrigin: true,
  })
);

// Start the Express server on your desired port
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000; // Use an appropriate port
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Proxy server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Now, I'd like to perform DOM manipulation but it is not working. Below is my code so far:

```
const express = require("express");
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

const app = express();

// Define your proxy rules here
app.use(
  "/", // Replace with the path you want to proxy
  createProxyMiddleware({
    target: "https://www.lemonade.com/",
    changeOrigin: true,
    onProxyRes: (proxyRes, req, res) => {
      let body = [];

      proxyRes.on("data", (chunk) => {
        body.push(chunk);
      });

      proxyRes.on("end", () => {
        body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();

        // Use Cheerio to load the HTML content
        const $ = cheerio.load(body);

        // Now you can manipulate the DOM using Cheerio
        // For example, let's change the title of the page
        $("title").text("Modified Title");

        // Set the manipulated HTML content as the response
        const modifiedHTML = $.html();
        console.log("modifiedHTML:", modifiedHTML);

        // Send the response here, outside of the Cheerio operations
        res.send(modifiedHTML);
      });
    },
  })
);

// Start the Express server on your desired port
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000; // Use an appropriate port
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Proxy server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

It looks like I'm missing something.

Comment: Please don't [repost your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77124389/dom-manipulation-of-proxy-response-in-express-node).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DOM manipulation of proxy response in express node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77124389/dom-manipulation-of-proxy-response-in-express-node)

Comment: @ggorlen where is the answer?

Comment: It's a standard system-generated dupe suggestion message.

Comment: No worries. Did I provide you enough information in my question to help you answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `selfHandleResponse: true` option because along with your call `res.send`, `res.end` is being called automatically, hence [the headers already sent error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client), and this flags prevents it:

```
 createProxyMiddleware({
    target: "https://www.lemonade.com/",
    changeOrigin: true,
    selfHandleResponse: true,
    onProxyRes: (proxyRes, req, res) => {
        //...
```

see:

> **option.selfHandleResponse** true/false, if set to true, none of the
> webOutgoing passes are called and it's your responsibility to
> appropriately return the response by listening and acting on the
> proxyRes event

```
/**
 * IMPORTANT: avoid res.end being called automatically
 **/
selfHandleResponse: true, // res.end() will be called internally by responseInterceptor()
```

[example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware#intercept-and-manipulate-responses)